Correlation Coefficient Significance in EdgeR?
How do I calculate or extract the p-value of coefficients in my GLM in edgeR? I want to gauage empirically the contribution of each of the coefficients to the model.
For reference, my design is:
Timepoint <- factor(meta.data_sub$Group3, levels = c("0","1"))
Age <- as.numeric(meta.data_sub$Age)
Sex <- factor(meta.data_sub$Sex2)
Ethnicity <- factor(meta.data_sub$Eth2)
design <- model.matrix(~Age + Sex + Ethnicity + Timepoint)

And I'm using QLFTest
dge <- estimateDisp(dge, design = design)
fit <- glmQLFit(dge, design = design, dispersion = dge$common.dispersion, contrast = contrast)
qlf <- glmQLFTest(fit)


What is meta.data_sub? Add library(edgeR) if edgeR is a package and needed to run your design. Have a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

You might add contrasts= in edgeR::glmQLFTest, but I don't know exactly how at the moment.

Use the coef argument im glmQLFTest which takes either the index number or name of the coefficient, see the help page of the function.

...though I would probably explore data by correlating principal components with the covariates to see if any is correlated, and only include covariates that explain any variation.

Thanks for the response. Like I said, I have no formal bioinformatics training so can you ELI5 how I would correlate PCA with covariates?

If you want a package for this maybe https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DEGreport.html -- iirc it has a function for this. Basically, it is just computing the prcomp() PCs and then run cor() between each PC with each covariate. You might want to look for local guidance if this is all new to you and you want to trust results without hitting many obstacles. Learning by doing is fine, but naturally many errors are made on the way. That's normal, we all do that, don't worry. Depends how soon the results must be trustworthy in your proejct.
